Can content from GitHub be cached via Cloudflare
My GithHub Pages site (custom domain with CloudFlare) uses some data from raw.githubusercontent.com.
CloudFlare caches all the content server from my domain as expected but I'm looking into ways to utilise CloudFlare caching for the remaining content.
I can't move the content onto my own domain as it exceeds GitHub Pages storage limit of 1 GB.
I tried setting up a CNAME redirect in CloudFlare to raw.githubusercontent.com but ran into issues.
Is this possible?
